# My hangman program is stuck at asking for input and not printing any letters i guess

Tags: python

I am quite new to programming and I tried making a program like hangman. However I just can't figure out why it's not working. All it does is it asks for input and then does nothing. The input just loops over and over again and nothing changes whatever I type in.
Also any tips on how to improve my code are welcome, I feel like I've done a lot of mistakes here.

```
import random

word_list = ["car", "house", "shop", "shoes", "tractor", "microphone", "camera"]

game_state = True

blank_spaces = []
word_picked = ""
already_guessed = []
word_letters = []


def Word_picker():
    word_number = random.randint(0, (len(word_list) - 1))
    word_picked = word_list[word_number]
    word_picked = word_picked.lower()
    word_letters = [char for char in word_picked]

    print("\n")
    print(word_picked)
    print(word_letters)
    print("\n")
    for char in word_letters:
        blank_spaces.append("_ ")


def Printer():
    print("\n \n")
    for x in range(len(blank_spaces)):
        print(blank_spaces[x], end='')


def Main():

    guessed_letter = input("Try a letter:")
    guessed_letter = guessed_letter.lower()

    if guessed_letter in already_guessed:
        print("You've already tried this letter. Try a different one. \n")
        Main()

    for z in word_letters:
        if guessed_letter == word_letters[z]:
            blank_spaces[z] = guessed_letter + " "
            already_guessed.append(guessed_letter)
            Main()

        else:
            print("Incorrect.")
            already_guessed.append(guessed_letter)
            Main()


def Already_guessed():
    for a in already_guessed:
        print("Already guessed letters:" + already_guessed[a] + ", ", end='')


Word_picker()
Printer()

while game_state:
    Already_guessed()
    Printer()
    Main()
```

Comment: You never return from `Main()`. All the conditions call itself recursively.

Comment: `z` is a letter, not an index. `word_letters[z]` should report an error.

Comment: you never check that all the letters have been guessed.

Comment: also, you do not change the lists `word_letters` and `word_picked`, they remain both empty if you inspect them in the `Main()` function.

Comment: Try not doing it with recursion for now but with a simply `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

I did some changes:

1. as pointed our by @Barmar, you are never returning the `Main()` function. I am now calling the function in a loop until gam_state changes to False.
2. also pointed out by @Barmar, you are using `z` as index which gives you an `IndexError`. `z` is already `already_guessed[i]` so you don't need that.
3. you are only changing the lists locally in the `Word_picker`, which did not work. I changed it to return the respective words and now you can access those from the `Main()` function.
4. you added the guessed letter in the for loop over all letters of the word, which did not break your code but itmade the output horrible and for more guessed causes your code to get unnecessary slow.
5. then some changes to your output so you only print text once outside the loop, etc.

```
import random

word_list = ["car", "house", "shop", "shoes", "tractor", "microphone", "camera"]

game_state = True

blank_spaces = []
word_picked = ""
already_guessed = []
word_letters = []


def Word_picker():
    w_number = random.randint(0, (len(word_list) - 1))
    w_picked = word_list[w_number]
    w_picked = w_picked.lower()
    w_letters = [char for char in w_picked]

    print("\n")
    print(w_picked)
    print(w_letters)
    print("\n")
    b_spaces = []
    for char in w_letters:
        b_spaces.append("_ ")
    print(b_spaces)

    return b_spaces, w_picked, w_letters


def Printer():
    print("\n \n")
    for x in range(len(blank_spaces)):
        print(blank_spaces[x], end='')


def Main():

    guessed_letter = input("Try a letter:")
    guessed_letter = guessed_letter.lower()
    print(already_guessed)

    if guessed_letter in already_guessed:
        print("You've already tried this letter. Try a different one. \n")

    for i, z in enumerate(word_letters):
        if guessed_letter == z:
            blank_spaces[i] = guessed_letter + " "

        else:
            print("Incorrect.")

    already_guessed.append(guessed_letter)


def Already_guessed():
    print("Already guessed letters:")
    for a in already_guessed:
        print(a)


blank_spaces, word_picked, word_letters = Word_picker()
Printer()

while game_state:
    Already_guessed()
    Printer()
    Main()
```

Some Tipps for future work:

1. use `print` statements or `import pdb;pdb.set_trace()` for debugging, so you know what your code is doing
2. write short, small elements first and test straight away, don't code everything up from scratch and look later. Try to test-run your code early and see if it is behaving as desired.
3. usually, its a good rule of thumb that you want to call your main function only once.

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't working for a number of reasons, but let's walk through some tips on how to debug your code and get it working.

An IDE-agnostic way of debugging is to add print statements to help figure out if your variables contain the values that you think they should.

Try adding this print statement `print("This is word_letters: ", word_letters)` in your Main() function before the line starting with `for z in word_letters:`

Ask yourself:

1. What do I expect this to return?
2. What does this actually return?
3. If there is anything unexpected, what is causing this?

For the print statement above: you'll find that your word_letters returns an empty list.
Is this what you expect?

Try doing this with the if statements and function calls.

If you work your way through your Main() and function calls, you should be well on your way to figuring out how to get your program running :)